# overloading operator<<. This operator is not a friend of class

Tags: c++

I have to overload:

```
ostream& operator<<();
```

This must be implement as method so I can't do it as friend. How to do it?

Comment: Can you reword your question so that it's more clear what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Why it must be implemented as a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will write this operator as a member function then it will only confuse users because the left operand of the operator will be an object of your class type instead of std::ostream.
So you could write your own member function instead of the operator. For example

```
class YourClass
{
public:
   std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os ) const
   {
      // some output
      return os;
   }
//...
};
```

You could also use this function inside the definition of the operator as a non-member function of the class. For example

```
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const YourClass &obj )
{
   return obj.out( os );
}
```